# Creating a checkbox array in .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application with a need to select all of the states (US) where a service is available.  For convenience, I was trying to create the list from an enum "State", displayu array as checkboxes and save selected to database.  Can't figure out the best way to create this.

Here is the class:

```
public class Offering
    {
        public int OfferingID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<State> States { get; set; }
    }

public enum State
    {
        AL, AK, AZ, CA, CO, CT, DC, DE, FL
    }
```

New to MVC so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way without having to write your own model binders would be something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>State</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (State state in Enum.GetValues(typeof(State)))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.States[state.ToString()].IsStateSelected)</td>
            <td>@state.ToString()</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Using this approach, you would need to make a new class, StateViewModel:

```
class StateViewModel
{
    public bool IsStateSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and an additional property in your Offering model,

```
public Dictionary<string, bool> States { get; set; }
```